# Assigning values in Drop Downs from JSON using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui

I have some JSON in this format:

```
"states": [
{"state":"AL","stateDescription":"Alabama","featured":"A1"},
{"state":"AK","stateDescription":"Alaska","featured":"B1"}
]
```

And i'm populating a drop down menu, i've been trying to assign the Option Value to the State, and the Value displayed to the stateDescription, but keep getting errors.  I've tried following a few tutorials on here but none seem to work.

This is my code to populate the dropdown:

```
 function populateDropdown(data) {
     var info = JSON.parse(data);
     var getStateDesc = _.pluck(info.states, 'stateDescription');
     var renderOptions = _.map(getStateDesc, function (val) {
         return '<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>';
     }).join();
     $('#myComboBox').html(renderOptions).selectpicker("refresh");
 };
```

So this successfully populates the drop down, however the option value is the same as the description, so when i'm trying to remove it at a later date it's not working, because the values need to be the 'state' not stateDescription.

How do i get the first `<option value="' + val + '">'` to equal the State?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var data = {
     "states": [{
         "state": "AL",
         "stateDescription": "Alabama",
         "featured": "A1"
     }, {
         "state": "AK",
         "stateDescription": "Alaska",
         "featured": "B1"
     }]
 }
 $(data.states).each(function (i) {
     $("#myComboBox").append($("<option/>", {
         val: this.state,
         html: this.stateDescription
     }));
 });
 });
```

**Html**

```
 <select id="myComboBox"></select>
```

First of all, your json is not valid. You need `{` and `}` at start and end. Then you can loop through the json. Use `.append()` method to add option to select.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7aGEv/39/)

Comment: I went with this one because it just seemed cleaner.  Used this to retro fit some other code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var jso={
    "states": [
        {
            "state": "AL",
            "stateDescription": "Alabama",
            "featured": "A1"
        },
        {
            "state": "AK",
            "stateDescription": "Alaska",
            "featured": "B1"
        }
    ]
}

function populateDropdown() {
     var output='';
     var dat= jso.states;
     for(var i in dat)
         {
             output+= '<option value="' + dat[i].state + '">' + dat[i].stateDescription + '</option>';
         }

     $('#myComboBox').html(output).selectpicker("refresh");
 }
populateDropdown();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j9KF5/16/)